# Google chart - Coloumn Chart Y-axis not visible

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

[This is how the image looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnxFS.png)

How do i get the y-axis? I want the y-axis as well. I am sorry if this was already asked but any help will be deeply appreciated. I searched a lot but was not able to find what I want.

The code used so far is this

```
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {  
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
     ['Element', 'Density', { role: 'style' }],
     ['Copper', 8.94, '#b87333'],            // RGB value
     ['Silver', 10.49, 'silver'],            // English color name
     ['Gold', 19.30, 'gold'],
     ['Platinum', 21.45, 'color: #e5e4e2' ], // CSS-style declaration
]);

var options = {
  legend: {
      position: 'none'
  },
  hAxis: {
        textPosition: 'none',
        title: "Weeks",
        maxValue:110,
        minValue:0        
    },
vAxis:{
        textPosition: 'none',
        title:"No of Chapters/Test",
        minValue:0
    },   
};
var chart = new    google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('container'));
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', afterDraw);
chart.draw(data, options);
```

Adding the JSFiddle link to it as well!
https://jsfiddle.net/9werg98u/

Comment: I have added the whole code for your reference. Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: Fixed it! The string in the data was the issue. :)

Answer (score 0):

just remove textPosition: 'none' at hAxis and vAxis